# Canon built-in intervalometer and image preview

Tags: canon, timelapse, intervalometer

I'm using the built-in intervalometer on my Canon 77D camera to shoot timelapses. I'd like to be able to asses the images by checking out the histogram on the preview (so I can adjust exposure properly when doing a sunset timelapse).

I noticed that if the interval is shorter than 7 seconds the preview won't show up on the LCD. Only for intervals of 7 seconds and longer the preview appears. Is there any setting for it?

I'd like to shoot in 5 seconds interval and still be able to see the preview after each shot.

Comment: Without the intervalometer, how long does it take the camera to show a preview when you take a photo using the exact same settings? (ISO, Image quality, NR, lens correction, etc.)